# Filter Clustering Mapbox GL JS

Tags: clustering, filter, mapbox-gl-js

According to @Mourner in this gihub issue regarding filtering cluster in Mapbox [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/2626).

> "you'll have to filter manually and run setData to reset the whole
>   dataset..."

I have also found an example of this in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2b8v7swq/).

But how do I set a filter in the .setData method?

My html:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="filter" alt="Arrive">
        <i class="fas fa-ship"></i>
        <span class="">Arrive</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

my js:

```
$(".filter").click(function () {
  var filter_key = $(this).attr("alt");
  var filter = ["==", 'navtag', filter_key];
  map.getSource('points').setData(**filtered data**);
..
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe he means that you should run a filter function over the data you use in `setData`. So if your data is an array of points with properties, you must *first* eliminate those points that do not meet your `navtag` criteria (in this case). This may involve using `setData` several times if your condition is dynamic.

This will probably look something like:

```
data.features = data.features.filter(feature => feature.navtag === 'foo')
map.getSource('points').setData(data)
```

Comment: Thanks @Richard Law. It sounds like setData expects a geojson? Can I see an example of filtering the geojson before passing filtered dataset to setData?

Comment: Added an example.